# Why can't the AudioRecord API on Samsung Galaxy S8 record clean 11kHz audio?

Tags: android, audio-recording, samsung-galaxy

Trying to record using AudioRecord API on Samsung Galaxy S8 with following code fails, resulting in invalid (too slow?) recording [(see this sample)](http://www.mediafire.com/file/0h2mkfcb06uk7fm/Samsung_Galaxy_S8_%2528primarydevice%2529_Android9_11khz_frontmic.wav/file):

```
int BUFFER_SIZE_FACTOR = 2;
int SAMPLING_RATE_IN_HZ = 11025;
int CHANNEL_CONFIG = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
int AUDIO_FORMAT = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

int BUFFER_SIZE = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLING_RATE_IN_HZ,
        CHANNEL_CONFIG, AUDIO_FORMAT) * BUFFER_SIZE_FACTOR;

recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT, SAMPLING_RATE_IN_HZ,
                CHANNEL_CONFIG, AUDIO_FORMAT, BUFFER_SIZE);

recorder.startRecording();
```

Why does this code not produce clear audio samples on a Samsung Galaxy S8? What am I doing wrong?

Is this an undiscovered hardware bug with Samsung Galaxy devices?

Unfortunately, I have as yet been unable to get a clear admission from Samsung.

If you can, contribute your results on S7, S9, and S10 devices (stating the Android version), it may help to nail down what the failing devices have in common. You can use e.g. “AudioRec Voice Recorder” by “AC SmartStudio”. It will allow sample rate configuration of 11kHz.

Results so far:

```
| Make    | Model    | Android | Reproduction |
|---------|----------|---------|--------------|
| Samsung | S7       |         |      ?       |
| Samsung | S8       |       8 |      Y       |
| Samsung | S8       |       9 |      Y       |
| Samsung | S9       |         |      ?       |
| Samsung | S10      |         |      ?       |
| Samsung | Duos A7  |       9 |      N       |
| Samsung | GT-l9300 |     4.3 |      N       |
| LG      | X20      |       6 |      N       |
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question?

Comment: @CommonsWare - cleared up the ambiguity for you.